# css won't respond when changing resolutions

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design, media-queries

I am working with a custom theme in wordpress and I'm wanting to add certain formatting when viewing from mobile (320px min - 400 max)

Meta Tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

css:

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {

.logo{margin-left:0px !important}
.content{width:100% !important; }
.mainmenu {background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6) !important; }
.mainmenu li{padding:0 5px !important;}
.mainmenu li a{font-size:18px !important; font-family:'impactregular' !important;     color:#000 !important;}   
}

@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1000px) {
    .logo{float:left;}
}
```

Now for some reason it detects the 1000px but not the smaller..not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Here's a [link](http://consultingfox.com/gc/) to the site I'm trying to fix.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change min-device-width to min-width and max-device-width to max-width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will help you.
[Media Queries for standard devices.](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

And use it as your meta tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
```

Comment: that where I got the info from aswell and even adding what you suggested it still doesn't display the way i want for iphone.. :S